# Using a dual core netbook as desktop

Tags: netbook

I feel silly asking this.

Is it possible to hook up a full sized monitor and keyboard and use the netbook closed?

Is gonna feel like those mini PC's or "nettops" as they call them. But I really like the portability plus.

Comment: It really depends on your make of netbook. Maybe you could give a bit more information? My Eee PC 701 does this just fine.

Comment: The answers are along the right lines - as long as it supports those connections, will drive the resolution of your monitor, then yes.  I /would/ point out for the same cost you can get a lot more processing power, an optical disk drive, more storage, etc in a cheap desktop, and I do mean A LOT.  But yeah, you lose out on the portability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will depend on the monitor and netbook you are buying.

Netbooks are cheap, and therefore many of aren't as fully featured as laptops are.
You will need to identify if the netbook has a **HDMI** or **VGA** output, and if the monitor has either of those as well.

Also because netbooks are generally small, manufacturers aren't able to fit many ports onto them. So make sure that the netbook has either a HDMI or VGA output.

Comment: My netbook sure has a VGA port, but for now I have an intel atom with a single core processor. The dual core netbooks I expect have not yet arrived in my country, Considering the new graphics standard of ION2  from Nvidia, I guess they use an HDMI port now? I think I can be sure asking when I buy it. Oh and thanks for your answers! By the way, I have an acer aspire one n2550 or something. It's red, I just love netbooks, they are super cute.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on the graphics standard, but yes I do agree, it may well have a HDMI port. Can you not visit the website/retailer you purchased/are purchasing the netbook from and see if it has a HDMI port listed as being on the device?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't. dual core netbooks haven't arrived in my country yet. The stores are full of single cored atoms for now. I mentioned I have a single core netbook with a vga port. I have yet to purchase the monitor I need, but I think I'll wait until the dual core netties arrive here.

Comment: Ok, make sure you check that the netbook as a HDMI or VGA port before you purchase it. As long as it has either of those ports, you will be able to connect it up with a TV or computer monitor and use it with an external keyboard and mouse.

Answer (score 5):

Yes,  as long as the netbook has a video out port of some sort and you have at least one open USB port for your keyboard.  You might need to get a USB hub to allow more devices usage as I am sure you will want an external mouse and possibly a port open for a printer or thumb drive.

Just turn off the option to sleep when lid is closed on the netbook and you should be good to go.  You toggle through the video modes so only the external display is used.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can definitely do this (as long as you have video port), the keyboard and mouse will just work. The monitor you will have to either clone or turn on single display just on the monitor through the Intel graphics control panel or the windows display options.